# How to define a triple layer dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization, data-structures

I want to create the following structure for a dictionary:

```
{ id1: {id2: {id3: [] }}}
```

That would be a triple dictionary that will finally point to a list.

I use the following code to initiate it in Python:

```
for i in range(2160):
    for j in range(2160):
        for k in range(2160):
            subnetwork.update({i: {j: {k: [] }}})
```

This code takes too much time to execute. It is of Big-O(N^3) complexity.

Are there any ways to speed-up this process? Serializing maybe the data structure and retrieving it from hard drive is faster?

What data structures can achieve similar results? Would a flat dictionary using three-element tuples as keys serve my purpose?

Comment: `i[0]` ?? that should throw an error.

Comment: Unless you have a system with *huge* memory, your structure is too large. You're creating 10 billion lists. Every list will be at least a dozen bytes, so at the very least it would require 100GB ram. And that's not counting the dicts.

Comment: do you actually want a nested dictionary with 2160**3 = 10 077 696 000 lists ?

Comment: @JulienSpronck Yes I edited it thank you.

Comment: So this structure that I want to achieve is not possible to do?

Comment: @drizo: no it's not. I just checked cpython's internal list representation, it needs 28 bytes for an empty list, so what you are trying to create takes **263GB** of memory, just for the lists. (actual size will vary depending on your system's `ssize_t`, I took 32 bits for a minimum value, but you're likely getting a 64-bit one).

Comment: @spectras Alright, thank you. I have changed the question a little. I am looking for approaches that will help me create a structure close to the 3 nested dictinaries.

Comment: `_dict[(id1, id2, id3)]` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need 10 billion entries (2,160 ** 3 == 10,077,696,000) in this structure? It's unlikely that any disk-based solution will be quicker than a memory-based one, but at the same time your program might be exceeding the bounds of real memory, causing "page thrashing" to occur.

Without knowing anything about your intended application it's hard to propose a suitable solution. What is it that you are trying to do?

For example, if you don't need to randomly look up items you might consider a flat dictionary using three-element tuples as keys. But since you don't tell use what you are trying to do anything more would probably be highly speculative.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes I am look for alternative approaches to this kind of structure. What you suggested at the end is a good idea, I will try to implement right now. Are there any other similar approaches like the three-element tuples?

Comment: There are usually many alternative approaches to a problem, depending on what it is you actually want to do. A little more information about the problem you are trying to solve will probably help.

Comment: @drizo> at this point, I think you should go googling about that then, if you're still stuck, ask another question stating your actual purpose, which we know nothing about.

Comment: @holdenweb your suggestion about the three element tuples is cool and I think it will work for me. But let's wait a bit to see if there are other suggestions on how to to create something like the triple dictionary.

Comment: Are the key sets sparse (_i.e._ will entries for most possible keys not exist)? If so it might be possible to use three levels of `collections.defaultdict` to ensure that keys are added on the fly.